# AngularJS "Controller as" in templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding

I am new to AngularJS world and I am trying to setup a basic laravel/angular JWT auth following [this tutorial](http://justinvoelkel.me/laravel-angularjs-part-two-login-and-authentication/).

What I'd like to do, it's to use the "Controller As" syntax instead of the `$scope` as stated in the tutorial. For now, here what I have:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.run(function () {});
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'js/templates/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    });
});
```

**login controller**

```
angular.module('app')

    .controller('LoginController', function ($scope) {
        this.title='toto';
        this.data = {};
        this.submit = function () {
            console.log(this.data);
        };
    });
```

**admin view**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Blog Administration</title>
        <!--css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

        <!--js-->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!--angular-->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/loginController.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="container" id="view" ng-view>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**login template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="LoginController as login">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="login" class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div id="login-form">
          <h4>{{ login.title }}</h4>

          <form ng-submit="login.submit()"><!--username-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <input id="username" type="text" ng-model="login.data.username"/>
            </div>
            <!--password-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <input id="password" type="password" ng-model="login.data.password"/>
            </div>
            <!--submit-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that nothing renders. Is it possible to use a controller per template ?

If I put the `<ng-controller="LoginController as login">` directive in the view body instead of template everything renders correctly.

Is it a good practice to define a controller per template ? Because the login template should be as generic as possible, so it can be loaded in any view if the user isn't authenticated, that's why I think putting login() action in the controlelr handling the Admin view is wrong.

Can someone advice me on the best practices to have here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use `controllerAs` syntax with [`routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) you need to declare additional property in route configuration:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'js/templates/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController',
    controllerAs: 'login'
});
```

Then you need to clean up login template, removing everything but actual template, e.g. no HTML, body tags, etc. You also don't need extra `ngController` directive in partial template:

```
<div id="login" class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div id="login-form">
        <h4>{{ login.title }}</h4>

        <form ng-submit="login.submit()">
            <!--username-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="username" type="text" ng-model="login.data.username" />
            </div>
            <!--password-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="password" type="password" ng-model="login.data.password" />
            </div>
            <!--submit-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, it works great ! Is this enough *angular way* of dealing with templates and their data ?

Comment: Yes, this is typical Angular approach for dealing with routes and partial views.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Question 1: Is it possible to use a controller per template ?
 Ans: Yes. Its very simply. How, is shown in next answer.

 Question 2: Is it a good practice to define a controller per template ?
 Ans: As per the AngularJs shown rules, Its good practice. Now see the 2
 different way of defining the controller for the template.

a. Directly into the template like: <div ng-controller="myCtrl">Whole template
   data goes inside this div.</div>

b. from the app.js where we load the template like this:

        .state('app.products.all', {
            url: '/all',
            templateUrl: 'tpl/products/blocks/thumb.html',
            controller: 'ProductsAllCtrl'
        })

 Here i have also shown the controller with the template path. Second way is
 more better then the first.
```